# Automatic signing failed. Xcode failed to provision this target. Please file a bug report

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

Error: Xcode failed to provision this target. Please file a bug report at https://feedbackassitant.apple.com and include the Update Signing report from the report navigator.

[image]

After upgrade of Xcode, MacOS and React Native running the app on a connected real device using Xcode and local environment cannot be done because build process shows the above error.

Environment:

```
    OS: macOS 13.1
    CPU: (16) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-9880H CPU @ 2.30GHz
    Memory: 33.82 MB / 16.00 GB
    Shell: 5.8.1 - /bin/zsh
  Binaries:
    Node: 16.10.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.10.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.18 - /usr/local/bin/yarn
    npm: 7.24.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v16.10.0/bin/npm
    Watchman: 2022.03.21.00 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
  Managers:
    CocoaPods: 1.11.3 - /usr/local/bin/pod
  SDKs:
    iOS SDK:
      Platforms: DriverKit 22.2, iOS 16.2, macOS 13.1, tvOS 16.1, watchOS 9.1
    Android SDK:
      API Levels: 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33
      Build Tools: 27.0.3, 28.0.3, 29.0.0, 29.0.2, 29.0.3, 30.0.0, 30.0.2, 30.0.3, 31.0.0, 31.0.0, 32.0.0, 32.1.0, 33.0.0, 33.0.0, 33.0.0, 33.0.0, 33.0.1
      System Images: android-26 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-26 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-27 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-27 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-28 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Google X86_ARM Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-29 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-29 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-29 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom_64, android-30 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-30 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-30 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom, android-30 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom_64, android-31 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-31 | Google APIs ARM 64 v8a, android-31 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-31 | Google Play ARM 64 v8a, android-31 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom_64, android-32 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-32 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom_64, android-33 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-33 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom_64
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

**There was a problem with provisioning profiles of one of my project targets, `<MyProjectName>Tests` one.** After react native and Xcode update it seems that there is a need for valid profiles for that target to. I removed that target because I don't need it and building and running on real connected devices work now.

Steps:

- checked all the certificates
- updated my provisioning profiles
- checked signing for all targets
- removed the test target because that required signing and another update of the provisioning profiles and I didn't need it
- cleaned build folder and rebuilt

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/14193797

Comment: Thank you, I removed the chatGPT code and added my steps. I still consider the chatGPT one was bit more general and useful than mine :)